# What am I doing wrong in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, vector

This is a program to take two vectors in input using the `input()` function and then add up their elements to make a union vector named `union_arr`. We are using the `aunio()` function to do that.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> union_arr;

void input_arr(vector<int> x) {
    cout << "Kitne elements: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i { 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << ": ";
        int nm;
        cin >> nm;
        x.push_back(nm);
    } 

    cout << x[1];
}

void aunio(vector<int> x, vector<int> y) {
    for (int i { 0 }; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        union_arr.push_back(x[i]);
    } 

    for (int i { int(x.size()) }; i < (int(x.size()) + int(y.size())); ++i) {
        union_arr.push_back(i - x.size());
    }

    cout << union_arr[1];
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;

    input_arr(a);
    input_arr(b);

    aunio(a, b);

    cout << "Union Array:" << endl << "[";

    for (int i { 0 }; i < union_arr.size(); ++i) {
        cout << union_arr[i] << " ";
    } 

    cout << "]";
}
```

I was expecting a `vector(union_arr)` that has elements of both the vectors. Also we have considered the user will put unique numbers or else repetition is allowed in `union_arr`.

Comment: Why do you spam the tags C++14 and C++17? What is specific to them in your question?

Comment: the code is written in c++ so

Comment: *the user will put* Don't make us to guess user input. Post a [mcve] with hardcoded input values that replicate your issue. The code should not have `cin>>`.

Comment: Using [std::set<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to store both vector's values does this job automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The fifth line in your `anio` function is `union_arr.push_back(i-x.size());`. However, it should be `union_arr.push_back(y[i-x.size()]);` instead, i.e., it should be adding the corresponding element of `y` instead of just its index.

Comment: Your `input_arr()` function takes the input parameter **by value**. This will modify a **copy** of the input vector, not the caller's vector. You should take the parameter by reference `void input_arr(vector<int> &x)` instead.

Comment: Your second loop in `aunio` is incredibly over-complicated.  You don't need to involve `x` at all.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, still not working. the size of array a,b after taking input is still 0.

Comment: Stop tag spamming. Your question is about generic C++, with nothing that ties it to specific versions. Please use only the tags that actually apply to your question. Tags here have relevance and meaning, and should be used properly. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: @KenWhite, sorry bro new to this site. would take care in future.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the major issue with your code:

- In function `void input_arr(vector<int>& x)`, parametere `x` is `passes as value` instead of `passed as reference`
- In function `void aunio(vector<int> x, vector<int> y)`, the line `union_arr.push_back(i-x.size());` should be `union_arr.push_back(y[i-x.size()]);`

**Note:** There are some more code improvements required. But I think that is out of scope for now.

Following is working code. [See it working here](https://ideone.com/aooGlZ):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> union_arr;

void input_arr(vector<int>& x){
    cout<<"Kitne elements: ";
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i{0};i<n;++i){
        cout<<": ";
        int nm;
        cin>>nm;
        x.push_back(nm);
    } cout<< x[1];
}

void aunio(const vector<int>& x, const vector<int>& y){
    for(int i{0};i<x.size();++i){
        union_arr.push_back(x[i]);
    } for(int i{int (x.size())};i<(int(x.size())+int (y.size()));++i){
        union_arr.push_back(y[i-x.size()]);
    }

    cout<< union_arr[1];
}

int main(){
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;

    input_arr(a);
    input_arr(b);

    aunio(a,b);

    cout<<"Union Array:"<<endl<<"[";

    for(int i{0};i<union_arr.size();++i){
        cout<<union_arr[i]<<" ";
    } cout<<"]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should avoid global variables, and read up a bit more on what std::vector can do for you. This will simplify your code a lot (and it will be less likely to contain bugs because you reuse tested code from vector)

```
auto aunio(vector<int> x, vector<int> y) 
{
    std::vector union_arr{x}; // make a coppy of `x`
    union_arr.insert(union_arr.end(), y.begin(), y.end()); // use vector's insert https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

    // learn about range based for loops, avoid index based for loops if you can
    for(const auto& value : union_arr) 
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return union_arr; // This will not return a copy so it is efficient (return value optimization)
}
```